# Why don't DNS queries return the subnet mask?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, routing, subnet

Why doesn't the DNS server give the subnet mask of the queried host name? For forwarding to the next hop, the IP address as well as the subnet mask is required by the routing table matching algorithm (longest prefix match). So shouldn't the DNS server return the subnet mask too in order for a packet to be routed to the correct next hop?
I saw that the `Answers` field of a DNS query response contained only the following values (in Wireshark) :

```
Answers
    google.com: type A, class IN, addr 216.58.197.78
        Name: google.com
        Type: A (Host Address) (1)
        Class: IN (0x0001)
        Time to live: 300
        Data length: 4
        Address: 216.58.197.78
```

So who provides the subnet mask for deciding the next hop of a particular packet destined to `google.com`?

Comment: Because DNS know nothing about the mask and gateway

Comment: Then how is a packet routed based on only the IP address of the host?

Comment: Via routing tables on the host (your, remote and internet). Please read a bit about how routing work

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the routing table require the subnet mask for matching a query? The routing tables use the [longest prefix match algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match) for matching a particular query, right? How can it do that without the subnet mask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is DNS does not have anything to do with configuring routing, there are two completely different things.

Think of your routing table as a set of rules that determine how IP packets are set out from your machine.  The routing rules tell your computer where the next hop router is and allows you to send different groups of IPs  to different routers if you'd like based on IP address and netmasks.

DNS has nothing to do with routing.  After receiving a DNS response, your computer will likely try to make a connection to the IP address in the DNS response.  When making this connection, the networking stack will use the IP/netmask combinations in the routing table to determine which entry in the routing table matches the destination IP (or if no matches it will select the default route).  The stack then uses this entry in the routing table to determine where to send the packet so that it will eventually get to the destination IP.